# Trying to Delete a Contact PhysicalAddress results in ErrorSchemaValidation Response

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

When trying to delete a whole Address from a contact, I get a "The request failed schema validation" error. My request looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                   xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
                   xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <ns1:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010"/>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns2:UpdateItem ConflictResolution="AlwaysOverwrite" MessageDisposition="SaveOnly">
            <ns2:ItemChanges>
                <ns1:ItemChange>
                    <ns1:ItemId
                        Id="..."
                        ChangeKey=".."/>
                    <ns1:Updates>
                        <ns1:DeleteItemField>
                            <ns1:IndexedFieldURI FieldURI="contacts:PhysicalAddress" FieldIndex="Business"/>
                        </ns1:DeleteItemField>
                    </ns1:Updates>
                </ns1:ItemChange>
            </ns2:ItemChanges>
        </ns2:UpdateItem>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And here's my reply

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
    <s:Fault>
        <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">a:ErrorSchemaValidation
        </faultcode>
        <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">The request failed schema validation: The 'FieldURI' attribute is invalid - The
            value 'contacts:PhysicalAddress' is invalid according to its datatype
            'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types:DictionaryURIType' - The Enumeration constraint
            failed.
        </faultstring>
        <detail>
            <e:ResponseCode xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">ErrorSchemaValidation
            </e:ResponseCode>
            <e:Message xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">The request failed schema
                validation.
            </e:Message>
            <t:MessageXml xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
                <t:LineNumber>2</t:LineNumber>
                <t:LinePosition>717</t:LinePosition>
                <t:Violation>The 'FieldURI' attribute is invalid - The value 'contacts:PhysicalAddress' is invalid
                    according to its datatype
                    'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types:DictionaryURIType' - The Enumeration
                    constraint failed.
                </t:Violation>
            </t:MessageXml>
        </detail>
    </s:Fault>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Which is an attempt to delete the business address for a contract. The issue, however, is that there's no `contacts:PhysicalAddress` DictionaryFieldURI, only DictionaryFieldURI's for each field of the address. Likewise, I can't just pass in the `contacts:PhysicallAddresses` field URI, because that's not indexed as such I'm not able to specify *which* address to delete with that.

So what should my request look like to just delete the business physical address of a contact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They Physical addresses are an array of properties and can't be deleted the way your trying to do it, you need to go through each of the individual properties (eg City,Address etc) and delete the ones you want to make null. eg

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013_SP1" />
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <m:UpdateItem MessageDisposition="SaveOnly" ConflictResolution="AlwaysOverwrite">
      <m:ItemChanges>
        <t:ItemChange>
          <t:ItemId Id="AAMkADczNDE4YWEwLTdlZLrCDQAAE1MmZPAAA=" ChangeKey="EQAAABYAAAB1EEf9GOowTZ1AsUKLrCDQAAE1Vhdy" />
          <t:Updates>
            <t:DeleteItemField>
              <t:IndexedFieldURI FieldURI="contacts:PhysicalAddress:City" FieldIndex="Business" />
            </t:DeleteItemField>
          </t:Updates>
        </t:ItemChange>
      </m:ItemChanges>
    </m:UpdateItem>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Cheers
Glen